# NOT NULL constraint failed: DJANGO Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm following an udemy tutorial, and all it's going nice until I try to do a **POST** to create an article on the database.

When I send a **POST** to `/api/posts`

with ***Multipart form***:

```
title: What is Java?

description: Java

order: 1
```

I receive the error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.order
```

I can't find the solution to this specific situation. So I let you the code of my:

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from posts.models import Post

class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'created_at']
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from posts.models import Post
from posts.api.serializers import PostSerializer

class PostApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        serializer = PostSerializer(Post.objects.all(), many=True)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.POST)
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.POST)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=serializer.data)
```

I can do a `GET` request to my `api/posts` properly. The real problem is the `POST` request where I should create a new article/post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order field is not included in the serializer. You need to add `order` in the `fields`.

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'order, 'created_at']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize it could be that thing. Now I know that's something I have to be in consider

Answer (score 1):

You are using input as `title`, `description` and `order` but in your `serializer` you didn't mention `order` field so you need to mention `order` filed in your `serializer`

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'order, 'created_at']
```

Comment: Thank you and for Bhavya as well to make me watch this. I didn't know it could be this!